# How to modularize a legacy JavaScript project

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need to use webpack to build a legacy JS project that so far did not have a
build system.

The project is split up into ~30 JS files, all of which assign functions and
fields to a single global `myApp` mega-object.
Previously, all these files were included separately in one namespace. It looked
somewhat like this:

`myApp.js`:

```
const myApp = {
  saySomething: function(x) {
    console.log(x);
  },
  something: "something"
};
```

`someModule.js`:

```
myApp.anotherModule = {
  foo: function(x) {
    myApp.someModule.bar(x);
  }
};
```

`anotherModule.js`:

```
myApp.someModule = {
  bar: function(x) {
    myApp.saySomething(x);
  },
  start: function() {
    myApp.someModule.foo(myApp.something);
  }
};
```

The entrypoint would call `myApp.someModule.start()`, the control flow would
weave between the different parts of the mega-object.

I tried factoring out an `index.js` like so:

```
const myApp = require('./myApp');
myApp.someModule = require('./someModule');
myApp.anotherModule = require('./anotherModule');
```

(with the appropriate `module.exports` declarations in the respective files.)

But when e.g. `anotherModule`'s `start` function calls `myApp.someModule.foo()`,
that's not in scope. I can't bring it into scope with `require` in the module
itself — I'd have to include `someModule`, which would in turn have to include
`anotherModule`, etc.

Is there a way out of this mess without having to refactor the entire project
(and utterly break the test suite, etc.?)

In other words: can I use webpack to assemble a mega-object and not isolate its parts' respective scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass a myApp reference to the require

```
require('./someModule')(myApp);
```

and the module should export a function accepting myApp as parameter

```
myApp.anotherModule = function(myApp) {
  return {
       foo: function(x) {
       myApp.someModule.bar(x);
     }
  }
};
```

so

```
myApp.someModule = require('./someModule')(myApp);
```

executes the function and returns your object with functions binded to myApp